# Finding maximum weighted geometric mean in integer partition with fixed number of partitions

Tags: integer-partitions, discrete-optimization

In trying to find the maximum geometric mean given an integer $n$ and $k$ target partitions, where $n = \sum_{i=1}^k n_i$ and $\Pi_{i=1}^k n_i$ is maximal, we can find such $n_1, ..., n_k$ by splitting $n$ into $k$ integers that are as equal as possible.

For instance, to maximize the geometric product of 10 with 4 partitions, we get 10 = 3 + 3 + 2 + 2. To maximize the geometric product of 20 with 3 partitions, we get 20 = 7 + 7 + 6.

Is there anything that can be said about trying to find the maximum *weighted* geometric mean given an integer $n$, $k$ target partitions, and weight vector **w** = $(w_1, ..., w_k)$? That is, we want to maximize the product $$\Pi_{i=1}^k \left( n_i^{w_i} \right)$$
such that $n = \sum_{i=1}^k n_i$.

Some thoughts:

- Would splitting $n$ into $k$ integers that are as equal (weight-adjusted by division, with ties in favour of largest weights first) as possible work?
- Say for instance we have $n = 10$, $k = 2$, **w** = (1,2), then 10 = 3 + 7, weighted geometric product = $3^1\times 7^2 = 147$ (which is the higher than if we were to split it 4+6)
- Another example is $n = 20$, $k = 3$, **w** = (1,2,3), then 20 = 3 + 7 + 10, weighted geometric product = $3^1\times 7^2\times 10^3 = 147,000$ (which would be maximum)
- It seems that each of the factors (divided by their respective weights) should differ by no more than one.

I'm not sure how to begin proving this though.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your intuition is correct for integer $w$.  You can mimic a proof for the $w \equiv 1$ (unweighted) case, which is to show how to improve any solution that does not have that property.  That is, assume
$$\frac{n_i}{w_i} - \frac{n_j}{w_j} > 1$$
for some $i$ and $j$, and modify $n_i$ and $n_j$ in a way that preserves $n_i+n_j$ but increases $n_i^{w_i} n_j^{w_j}$.

Comment: I played around with some examples, and it turns out that that while this property holds (good to know though!), it's not really tight. Partitioning 20 = 3 + 7 + 10 and 20 = 3 + 8 + 9 with weights 1,2,3 both satisfies the condition, but the former achieves maximum weighted geometric mean.